# Prompt is made when navigating within same route

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

For the use case when a page has an internal route, the prompt triggers even when navigating to an internal route where a prompt might not be necessary, see code example. Is there a way to disable the prompt when navigating to known safe routes?

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Link, Prompt} from 'react-router-dom';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route component={About} path={"/about"}/>
          <Route component={Home} path={"/"}/>
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {input: 'hello?'}
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Home</h1>
        <input value={this.state.input} 
          onChange={(e) => this.setState({input: e.target.value})}/><br />
        <Link to={"/info"}>More Info</Link><br />
        <Link to={"/about"}>About Page</Link><br />

        {/*Triggers even when going to /info which is unnecessary*/}
        <Prompt message="Move away?" when={this.state.input !== 'hello?'}/>
        <Route path={"/info"} component={Info}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class About extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <h1>About page</h1>
    );
  }
}

class Info extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <p>Here be some more info</p>
    );
  }
}
```

In the example above, About is a different page and so should trigger when the input has changed, which it does correctly. But the /info route is an internal route for Home, so the prompt is unnecessary, the internal state of Home is preserved after navigation so nothing is lost.

The actual use case here is for a modal to be shown when the route is active, but that is mostly CSS stuff so I excluded it from the example.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think a callback function as a message prop is what are you looking for. You can try to give a callback function to `Prompt`'s message prop. That callback will be called with an object as an argument which will have all the information about the next route.

This is what [documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Prompt) says about it:

> message: func
>
> Will be called with the next location and action the
>   user is attempting to navigate to. Return a string to show a prompt to
>   the user or true to allow the transition.

The object has a `pathname` attribute which is the next path by checking it you can figure out if the path is safe. Here is what I'm talking about:

```
<Prompt message={(params) => 
        params.pathname == '/about' ? "Move away?" : true } />
```

And here is the [pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XReabZ) with working code which I've created from your examples.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Foolish me, must've missed that part of the documentation. Thank you! It did indeed solve my issue.